# Android AlertDialog.Builder justify text

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is there a way to justify the text in an AlertDialog?
Something like this for a TextBox since Oreo:

```
textView.setJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
```

I need same behaviour for a typical dialog like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
builder.setMessage("Long text to be justified");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
Dialog d = builder.create();
d.show();
```

Comment: Why not create a custom dialog with normal textview and then add a check to see whether the system version > android O and then apply justification?

Comment: Well, you are right, but sincerely, nowadays that should be done by the AlertDialog builder. In fact, that way of displaying text should be the default way. It is not "clean" to always program doing workarounds like that. Thanks anyway for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trick to justify text in `textview`

**Use a custom dialog** 
then use this custom `textview` in in your `dialog` `xml`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * @author ccheng
 * @Date 3/18/14
 */
public class JustifyTextView extends TextView {

    private int mLineY;
    private int mViewWidth;
    public static final String TWO_CHINESE_BLANK = "  ";

    public JustifyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        TextPaint paint = getPaint();
        paint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        paint.drawableState = getDrawableState();
        mViewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        String text = getText().toString();
        mLineY = 0;
        mLineY += getTextSize();
        Layout layout = getLayout();

        // layout.getLayout()在4.4.3出现NullPointerException
        if (layout == null) {
            return;
        }

        Paint.FontMetrics fm = paint.getFontMetrics();

        int textHeight = (int) (Math.ceil(fm.descent - fm.ascent));
        textHeight = (int) (textHeight * layout.getSpacingMultiplier() + layout.getSpacingAdd());

        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++) {
            int lineStart = layout.getLineStart(i);
            int lineEnd = layout.getLineEnd(i);
            float width = StaticLayout.getDesiredWidth(text, lineStart, lineEnd, getPaint());
            String line = text.substring(lineStart, lineEnd);
            if (needScale(line) && i < layout.getLineCount() -1) {
                drawScaledText(canvas, lineStart, line, width);
            } else {
                canvas.drawText(line, 0, mLineY, paint);
            }
            mLineY += textHeight;
        }
    }

    private void drawScaledText(Canvas canvas, int lineStart, String line, float lineWidth) {
        float x = 0;
        if (isFirstLineOfParagraph(lineStart, line)) {
            String blanks = "  ";
            canvas.drawText(blanks, x, mLineY, getPaint());
            float bw = StaticLayout.getDesiredWidth(blanks, getPaint());
            x += bw;

            line = line.substring(3);
        }

        int gapCount = line.length() - 1;
        int i = 0;
        if (line.length() > 2 && line.charAt(0) == 12288 && line.charAt(1) == 12288) {
            String substring = line.substring(0, 2);
            float cw = StaticLayout.getDesiredWidth(substring, getPaint());
            canvas.drawText(substring, x, mLineY, getPaint());
            x += cw;
            i += 2;
        }

        float d = (mViewWidth - lineWidth) / gapCount;
        for (; i < line.length(); i++) {
            String c = String.valueOf(line.charAt(i));
            float cw = StaticLayout.getDesiredWidth(c, getPaint());
            canvas.drawText(c, x, mLineY, getPaint());
            x += cw + d;
        }
    }

    private boolean isFirstLineOfParagraph(int lineStart, String line) {
        return line.length() > 3 && line.charAt(0) == ' ' && line.charAt(1) == ' ';
    }

    private boolean needScale(String line) {
        if (line == null || line.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return line.charAt(line.length() - 1) != '\n';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, you are right, but sincerely, nowadays that should be done by the AlertDialog builder. In fact, that way of displaying text should be the default way. It is not "clean" to always program doing workarounds like that. Thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: i am glad , i think it depends upon the usage , so according to your usage i would go for custom dialog , because you cannot rely on default alert dialog whose behaviour is different in different operating systems, that my thought , also Upvote my answer so others can refer it as well ... Happy coding